# How to initializate my IDbConnection and IConfiguration with Mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm wandering how to do this since It gives me nullreferenceexception. I have this constructor on my handler class:

```
        IDbConnection _dbConnection;
        Context _context;
        SigSettings _settings;
        public SignalsHandler(IConfiguration configuration, IDbConnection connection)
        {
            _dbConnection = connection;
            _settings = configuration.GetSection("SigSettings").Get<SigSettings>();
            if (_settings == null)
                _settings = new SigSettings();
        }
```

And I want to do unit test about this class to test my crud methods but the code below doesn't work:

```
private Mock<IConfiguration> _configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
        private Mock<IDbConnection> _connection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
        private readonly SignalsHandler _handler;

        public SignalsTest()
        {
            _handler = new SignalsHandler(_configuration.Object, _connection.Object);
        }
```

It gives me this error: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name' on this line:  _settings = configuration.GetSection("SigSettings").Get();

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_configuration` is just mocked object and you also need to setup methods it has, otherwise, they will return `null`, so `configuration.GetSection("SigSettings")` would return `null`.

To avoid that, you need to write:

```
_configuration
   .Setup(x => x.GetSection("SigSettings"))
   .Returns("some setting");
```

or more generally:

```
_configuration
   .Setup(x => x.GetSection(It.IsAny<string>()))
   .Returns("some setting");
```

**UPDATE**

As I did not realize that methods returns some object rather than `string`, here's full setup. Generally you always provide mocks for all the way of method calls, so nowhere you will get `null`:

```
var configSectionMock = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
var configMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
configMock
    .Setup(x => x.GetSection(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(configSectionMock.Object);

// Instantiate system under test with mocked object.
var sut = new Sut(configMock.Object);
```

Comment: Sorry If this is too obvious but in the .Returns() part what It should returns?

Comment: @Weenhallo whatever you want

Comment: If I return a string it says " cannot convert from string to "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection"

Comment: @Weenhallo Please, see update.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach not to mock `IConfiguration`, but provide actual implementation which provides useful feedback without coupling to the methods used in the class under the test.

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(new[] 
    { 
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SigSettings:One", "value1"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SigSettings:Two", "value2"),
    })
    .Build();

var sut = new Sut(configuration);
```

Now in the `Sut` you can use different ways to access configuration values without rewriting tests.